# What causes this lack of adhesion on the first layer

Tags: adhesion, elegoo-neptune-3

I just got an Elegoo Neptune 3 Pro and it's been printing great. Until now. I'm not sure what changed.

My first layer is acting funny. I get separation of the lines, but only where the extruder is moving in a specific direction.

[image: Photo of print showing "separation of lines" on one side of the brim]

When the head is moving in the x direction (left looking at the printer), it raises and doesn't adhere to the line next to it. Often the print will go on to work fine, but this is bothering me. The one side of the brim looks beautiful, and I want the entire brim to look that way.

I don't think it's a bed level issue. I see the issue just after a 36 -point bed level. I can also print a good skirt that covers the bed and there are no inconsistencies. If I printed two of the object in the image above, they would both have the issue despite one being positioned on another side of the bed. It has more to do with the direction the head is moving.